# Convert SAML token into JWT token using IdentityServer

Tags: wif, saml, federated-identity, jwt, ws-trust

I configured Thintecture Identity Server with identity federation (google, facebook, live id), and WCF SOAP service.

Now I need WCF Rest Endpoint (webHttpBinding) for Windows Phone application. I don't want to pass WSTrust SAML token in authorization header. Is possible to convert SamlToken into JWT token and how:)?

Below is code I tried, but doesn't work.

```
var factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(
    new WindowsWSTrustBinding(SecurityMode.Transport),
    new EndpointAddress("https://identityserver.local/issue/???"))
{
    TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13
};

var rst = new RequestSecurityToken
{
    RequestType =  RequestTypes.Issue,
    KeyType = KeyTypes.Bearer,
    TokenType = TokenTypes.JsonWebToken,
    AppliesTo = new EndpointReference("http://my.realm/")
};

var securityToken = xmlToken.ToSecurityToken();
var response = factory.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken(securityToken).Issue(rst);
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure IdentityServer to return JWT. Go to global config and change the default token type to JWT (same value as the default http token type). That should do it.

Update: Why are you using WSTrust at all - IdSrv does not support authentication with e.g. google over WS-Trust.

Comment: Thanks, for answer. I need two tokens... one SAML for WCF desktop client (WPF, Windows Store) and one for REST clients (Windows Phone, Android, iOS) or is possible to use JWT in both scenarios? 

Tomorrow I will try ACS Wrap Service... which will convert SAML into JWT/SWT. I don't now this will work?

And answering you question I use WS-Federation with (with home realm discovery) Google, Live Id, and Facebook. I intercept web request negotation between Identity Sarver and Facebook for example and get SAML token. When I get SAML token I tried to use WS-Trust to obtain JsonWebToken.

Comment: Yeah - this won't work - you can convert it manually (but that requires a signing key) or use ACS to convert it. None are perfect solutions ;) You could extend IdSrv to provide such a service for you, of course.

Comment: Extending IdSrv is great idea... this looks like very natural and simple solution. I will give try this way.